# Angular JS - No Access-Control-allow-origin - Directive template url

Tags: angularjs

i have a directive that get an html in a different domain (production environment) like this one:

```
app.directive("mydirective", ['$sce',function ($sce) {
return {
    controller: 'myController',
    templateUrl: function () {
        return  $sce.trustAsResourceUrl('urlwithadifferentdomain/myhtml.html');
    }
};}]);
```

I'm not able to load my page for no access controll allow origin issue.
I have not be able to solve my issue reading on the other stackoverflow question.
I have only my html and my JS page and i have to integrate them in my customer website.

Comment: Did you try to install cors on your browser ?

Comment: nope, but i can't use this solution for a production environment

Comment: Are you using any backend like (python,php,node) ?